How to force a set packing constraint to "become redundant" or "not require"?
This question is a follow up question to my previous discussion on the task of nullification for set partitioning constraint. Out of pure curiostity and for academic completeness, I just want to know how to handle the following case:
$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\mathop {Min}\limits_x }&{f\left( x \right)}\\
{{c_1}:}&{{x_1} + {x_2} +  {x_3} \le 1}\\
{{c_2}:}&{{x_2} + {x_3}  + {x_4} \le 1}\\
{{c_3}:}&{{x_4} + {x_5} +  {x_6}\le {y_1}}\\
{{c_4}:}&{{x_5} + {x_6}+  {x_7} \le {y_2}}\\
{}&{{x_1},{x_2},{x_3},{x_4},{x_5},{x_6},{x_7} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}}\\
{}&{{y_1},{y_2} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}}
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\rm{Constraints}}}&{{\rm{Control}}\,\,{\rm{Variables}}}\\
{{c_1}}&{{t_1}}\\
{{c_2}}&{{t_2}}\\
{{c_3}}&{{t_3}}\\
{{c_4}}&{{t_4}}
\end{array}$
Here $t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4 \in \{0,1\}$ with the rule ${t_i} = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{0,}&{{c_i}\,{\rm{become }}\,{\rm{redundant}}}\\
{1,}&{{{\rm{enforce }}\, {\rm{ constraint }}\,{c_i}}}
\end{array}} \right.$
Similar to the previous post, my question is "how can we reformulate this problem so that the set packing constraint $c_i$ become redundant or not needed ?"

Similarly to my answer to the linked question, you can rewrite $c_3$ and $c_4$ as set packing (like $c_1$ and $c_2$) by a change of variables $\bar{y}_i=1-y_i$. For example, $c_3$ becomes $x_4+x_5+x_6+\bar{y}_1 \le 1$.
You want to enforce $$t_i=1 \implies \sum_{j\in J_i} x_j \le 1.$$ Either directly use an indicator constraint or linearize via big-M:
$$\sum_{j\in J_i} x_j - 1 \le (|J_i|-1)(1-t_i)$$
Equivalently,
$$\sum_{j\in J_i} x_j \le |J_i|-(|J_i|-1)t_i \tag1\label1$$
For example, your $c_1$ has $J_1=\{1,2,3\}$, yielding $$\sum_{j\in \{1,2,3\}} x_j \le 3-(3-1)t_1$$
Similarly, your $c_3$ yields
$$x_4+x_5+x_6+(1-y_1) \le 4-(4-1)t_3$$

The conjunctive normal form approach yields
\begin{align}
t_i + x_j + x_k &\le 2 &&\text{for all $\{j,k\}\subseteq J_i$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}

For small $|J_i|\ge 2$, PORTA returns the following formulation with $2^{|J_i|} + |J_i|$ constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\in K} x_j &\le |K| - (|K|-1)t_i &&\text{for $K \subseteq J_i$} \\
x_j &\ge 0 &&\text{for $j\in J_i$}
\end{align}
Note that $|K|=0$ yields $t_i \ge 0$ and $|K|=1$ yields $x_j \le 1$.
